# Empty route globs in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, glob

I'm upgrading from Rails 2 to 3.1, and having some problems with route globs. We had working globbed routes in Rails 2 that were like this:

```
map.connect '/foo/*bar', :controller => 'foo', :action => 'index'
```

A GET to '/foo/one/two' would give the following parameters at the controller side:

```
{
  :controller => 'foo',
  :action => 'index',
  :bar => ['one, 'two']
}
```

Empty globs were fine, so we could also do GET '/foo' and get:

```
{
  :controller => 'foo',
  :action => 'index',
  :bar => []
}
```

Upgrading to Rails 3.1, there are a few differences:

```
match '/foo/*bar', :to => 'foo#index'
```

The globbed route segment comes through as a string instead of an array, but I've dealt with that in my code. No problem there. A GET '/foo/one/two' gives:

```
{
  :controller => 'foo',
  :action => 'index',
  :bar => 'one/two'
}
```

The problem comes when I have nothing in the glob segment. GET '/foo' is no longer routable, and if I try to generate the URL from parameters, it cannot generate. Basically, if params[:bar] is an empty string, it just completely fails to route.

This is awkward in my app, as it depends on the Rails 2.3 behaviour to produce sensible URLs. We also have instances where the glob is mid-path:

```
match '/foo/*bar/show', :to => 'foo#show'
```

This means that we had paths like:

```
/foo/one/two/show
/foo//show
```

Is there any way to get the routing engine to handle the empty strings as it used to in Rails 2.3? I've tried adding extra routes for the empty-glob version, which works in the simple trailing-glob case, but in the case where the glob is mid-path, it doesn't.

Comment: How did /foo//show match with your Rails 2.3 routes?

Comment: Same as for the index action, but with action => 'show'. Empty array for params[:bar].

Comment: `{ :controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => [] }`

Comment: So you had another map.connect for that.

Comment: No, there was just the one route. It just seemed to match empty segments as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get tests passing with these routes:

```
Your::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/foo/', :to => 'foo#index', :bar => ''
  match '/foo//show', :to => 'foo#show', :bar => ''
  match '/foo/*bar/show', :to => 'foo#show'
  match '/foo/*bar', :to => 'foo#index'
end
```

Sequence is important!

**Ambiguity**: Is /foo/show meant to "show foo-index", or do "index for bar=show"?

Test:

```
require_relative '../test_helper'

class FooRoutingTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test 'root index' do
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'index', :bar => ''}, '/foo')
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'index', :bar => ''}, '/foo/')
  end

  test 'root show' do
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => ''}, '/foo/show')
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => ''}, '/foo//show')
  end

  test 'wildcard index' do
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'index', :bar => 'hello'}, '/foo/hello')
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'index', :bar => 'hello/more'},'/foo/hello/more') 
  end

  test 'wildcard show' do 
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => 'wow'}, '/foo/wow/show')
    assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => 'wow/more'}, '/foo/wow/more/show')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At least I know I'm not doing something stupid. I've put your code above into my app, and it works. The problem resurfaces however when I try the inverse test: `assert_generates('/foo//show', {:controller => 'category', :action => 'show', :bar => ''})`. This fails, generating /foo/show instead of /foo//show. The others where bar is defined work, but this one misses the empty segment.

Comment: That could be because /foo/show is routing to the show action, whereas I don't actually want that, I don't think (at least for compatibility with the existing site). Will see if I can stop that happening (so only /foo//show routes to the show action), then it might work itself out. I guess it goes for the simplest option.

Comment: This passes: assert_generates('/foo/show', {:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => ''}), and is consistent with  assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => ''}, '/foo/show'). I find it a bit worrying that you can't have "bar=show". This passes, assert_generates('/foo/show', {:controller => 'foo', :action => 'index', :bar => 'show'}, but the reverse doesn't, assert_recognizes({:controller => 'foo', :action => 'index', :bar => 'show'}, '/foo/show') (goes to {"bar"=>"", "controller"=>"foo", "action"=>"show"}). Does this really work out with the Rails 2 setup?

Comment: Yeah, it all worked in Rails 2, has been in production for 2 years! In our app, it's OK that you can't have 'show' as a value for 'bar', so we live with the problem there.

Comment: The problem is that it can't generate /foo//show from any combination of options. We could of course use /foo/show (which works, as you say) but that would break a whole bunch of our existing URLs.

Comment: So you're saying in Rails 2, you get assert_generates('/foo//show', {:controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :bar => ''}) passing? To me with these Rails 3 routes, /foo//show is not generated, but it is recognized -- correctly. Similarly, /foo/show is handled correctly. So links that exist right now will work correctly. Just that the "new form" is produced.

Comment: You're right; I was so deep in the problem I forgot to step back. Incoming URLs route correctly in both forms, so it doesn't matter that my generated links use the single-slash form. Thanks very much for pointing that out :)